# fitting lines in an image

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to implement Edge drawing algorithm. I obtained lines of the image, the next step is fitting lines with a given treshold, my problem is that given a matrix of 1 and 0, (1 part of the lines) go through all the pixels and start fitting lines.
The idea is to generate a minimal length initial line segment by the least squares line fitting method, and then extend this line segment by adding more pixels to it. After the detection of a minimal length initial line segment, we should walk over the remaining pixels of the chain and compute the distance of each pixel to the currently fitted line. pixels are added to the current line  as long as the pixels are within a certain distance from the current line. we  continue adding pixels to the current line segment
until we turn a corner and the direction of the line changes. At that point, we output the current line segment. The remaining pixels of the chain are then processed recursively to extract further line segments.

My problem is that I don't know how to start going over the pixels...and if there is a specific direction I should first take...

Comment: By tagging C++ and Matlab, you mean solution by any of them is acceptable? C++ without some CV library like OpenCV will be so hard and redundant

Comment: You fail to provid enough context. Most of the things you are talking about are meaningless without any further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **flawr**. Without more info like input image and wanted result example is very hard to answer. I guess you got incomplete contours of some object and want to regress/extrapolate the gaps in 2D space. In that case I would:

1. **obtain the visible contour lines**

   You already have this.
2. **sort the lines by its direction angle**

   If line`(i)` endpoints are `A(i),B(i)` then:

   ```
   ang(i)=atan2(B(i).y-A(i).y,B(i).x-A(i).x)
   ```
3. **merge lines**

   merge all lines that has:

   - similar angle
   - are not too far
   - have small perpendicular distance (as if were parallel)
   - the merged line is not intersecting any other line
4. **close the gaps**

   After merging just find all the contours edge points. These points are connected to just single line. Now you can apply the extrapolation you propose in OP but I would try to connect the closest such points to each other with simple line instead (if the connection do not cross any line).